# ContentDocumentId is null when guest user is uploading a file in Salesforce site

Tags: visual-workflow, contentdocument, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

So I have a web-to-case scenario. I need to build a customer support form wherein the customer is able to fill out name, email, subject, description and attach files. Once he fills all the fields and attaches his files and submit the form, a case should be created with all the details and under the Case related list, Files object should have the attachment of the file uploade by the guest user.

To achieve this, first i enabled the general setting in salesforce files of "allow guest users to upload file" and enabled read/create access for case for guest user. I created a flow and through that flow, guest user is able to upload the file, create a case but the attachment is not getting updated on case. The debug log shows that the contentdocumentId is null. When i tried through admin login, the file is getting uploaded and updated on case as well because the contentdocumentid is getting created but the same is not happening for guest users.

Kindly let me know if you have faced a similar issue and how to get the value in contentdocument id

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.